# Unable to pass props to other components in react native navigation v2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-navigation

Unable to pass props to other components in react native navigation v2. I am getting undefined whenever I am trying to call that props in my component. I would like to notify that I am using redux in my project and I found a similar issue in StackOverflow but it didn't work for me.

React Native Navigation code:-

```
Navigation.push("FamilyStack", {
  component: {
    name: "com.radarx.FamilyFormScreen",
    passProps: {
      text: "Pushed screen"
    },
    options: {
      topBar: {
        title: {
          text: "Pushed screen title"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But when I am trying to use that prop it's giving me an error of type undefined.

I am trying to call the prop here just for checking if it's working for not.

```
class FamilyFormScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
console.log("screen: ", props);
```

}

Comment: Any chance you can share some of your code? Will be difficult to help you without seeing what you are working with.

Comment: @Lloyd update question with code

Comment: thanks Anmol can you share the code where you are trying to call the props as well.

Comment: @Lloyd updated question

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract from the props the correct params in order to "see" the params you are passing through navigation.

After `super(props)` you should be able to call `console.log("screen ", this.props)`

Comment: I am getting my other redux props in the console log but the props that I am passing from the push navigation API are not there in the console log

Comment: It will work if I am not using redux but with redux, it is not working I don't know why.

Comment: @AnmolSharma i have just edited. try and if not i recommend you to share all the code or create an Expo snack whit the code and share the link.

Comment: I think you haven't seen my question carefully I am using react-native-navigation V2 not react-navigation both the libraries are used for navigation in react native

Comment: @AnmolSharma you are right sorry. could you update an img from console.log(this.props) ??

Comment: @HelmerBarcos sorry but I can't update the image of the console log as the component contains some authentication props also but for your information, I would like to inform you that I am getting all the props from the redux side but only having issues with the navigation API, passProps attribute, whatever object I pass in that is not available as the props.

Comment: @AnmolSharma you should be able to catch the data as this.props.text in `FamilyStack` component. did you try it?

Comment: @HelmerBarcos thanks but I tried that it didn't work but know I think I found what was the issue and I resolved it in another way. The actual issue was with redux it was not allowing the react native navigation library to pass props. As in redux everything is passed through the central store system, so I just created a new variable the store for passing the details of the family member.

Thanks BDW